# Mapping data from RSS feed with no latitude/longitude using MapKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

Having follow the tutorial at http://mithin.in/2009/06/22/using-iphone-sdk-mapkit-framework-a-tutorial/ to integrate the MapKit into my application. However, I want to be able to display an annotation for a dynamic "incident" on the map. Here's where I'm having problems.

Basically my apps an RSS reader, and it downloads everything and saves each item of the feed (as in Story 1, Story 2) as currentItem. The data I want to grab and use to map the annotation can be found under currentItem.title - but I can't seem to get it to work in this tutorial's code or find the right place to put it.

The RSS feed I'm using doesn't have any latitude/longitude information either - making it even harder.

Any help would be great - I've been working on this for a couple of days now with still no luck.

UPDATE: I'm even considering launching the Google Maps application instead showing the annotation. But this in itself is raising issues. Below is the code I'm using but its throwing errors everywhere.

```
NSString *title = currentItem.title;
int zoom = 13;
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%@@%1.6f,%1.6f&z=%d", title, zoom];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: How are you planning to add an annotation without lat/long info? Where will it go? Besides this, what's the exact problem you're having (what errors are being thrown, etc)?

Comment: I was planning on using reverse lookup - that tutorial goes through all that (in the tut you enter an address and it then looks up the lat/long info). Now its not actually throwing any errors - when you click the button (I've placed this action in a UIActionSheet) nothing happens - it just closes the UIActionSheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just mapped the title using reverse lookup, and added the country afterwards so results would only be in the country where the address is. Not ideal, but it seems to work OK.